# Fragment title disappearing (perhaps after process was killed)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a simple `FragmentActivity` which contains three fragments, and each one includes the following method to set the title when the user scrolls to each fragment.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) { 
        getActivity().setTitle(pageTitle);
    }
}
```

`pageTitle` obviously differs depending on the fragment. This works as desired, except after leaving the application for a while sometimes when reopening (to the FragmentActivity) the title isn't there, nor does it get set when scrolling through the fragments. I was advised that this may be because of the application process being killed etc.

Does anybody have any idea how I could go about handling this situation? A possibility is maybe loading the app back from the main application after the process has been killed (not ideal, but due to the way my app works it shouldn't be a big deal), but I wouldn't know how to go about doing it.

Also, the pageTitle is set in the new instance of the Fragment which is called from the FragmentAdapter (shown below) - could this be the root of the issue because they're being rebuilt? Would it be better to just hardcode the text for the title?

```
public static Fragment newInstance(String title) {
    pageTitle = title;
    return new Fragment();
}
```

Would it solve the issue to set it via the following (I could test it but because it takes time, I figure I'll ask it here since I just thought of it):

`getActivity().setTitle("Page Title");`

I know there's probably some `onResume()` type deal to solve this, but I can't seem to get it working so any help/guidance/solution is appreciated. Hopefully I've made my question clear enough, if you want to know any more about my code just ask - but I'm pretty sure that's all that might be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as I thought in the question, either hardcoding the string or setting `pageTitle` inside `onResume()` fixed the issue.

Just to add a bit more to this answer:

`newInstance()` is only called upon the initial creation of the `FragmentActivity` so the string is only passed once. When the app is resumed later, `newInstance()` is not called, and the Fragments just rebuild themselves from where they were. Obviously because the string was not passed via `newInstance()`, the string `pageTitle` is now just null.

To combat this, I just hardcoded the strings in the classes:

`private String pageTitle = "myTitle";`

However, if it was only desirable to get it from your Adapter, you could always call getTitle from your adapter in your `onResume()` like this (it could be done a lot better, it's just for demo purposes):

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    pageTitle = new MyFragmentAdapter().getPageTitle(myPageNumber).toString();
}
```